# May one chew gum in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, food, derech-eretz-manners, bathroom

As per this post - [Food in bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/food-in-bathroom) - one may not eat in the bathroom. May one chew gum in the bathroom? Is it considered eating? Connected to this post - [Can you walk and chew gum at the same time?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12278/can-you-walk-and-chew-gum-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I heard live from HaGaon HaRav Yis'haq Yosef Shelita (author of Yalkut Yosef) that it is [Mutar](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591/647). He also said candies are Mutar in the bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

Just for additional information,
The Sepharadi Rabbi I asked (R' Shay Tahan) said that if the gum still has taste, then it's assur to keep it in one's mouth when going to the bathroom.

[This Ashkenazi site](https://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2019/07/halachically-speaking-chewing-gum-rabbi-moishe-dovid-lebovits.html) says that it is assur.

[This website](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/80958) says that it is נכון מאוד (very much proper) to not have the benefit of the taste from gum in the bathroom.